# Rails 3 validations and non REST URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, url, routes

I have a route setup like this:

```
match '/:url' => 'subjects#show'
```

In my Subjects controller I use

```
@subject = Subject.where("url = ?", params[:url].downcase).first
```

instead of

@subject = Subject.find(params[:id])

and this works just fine. The problem is that none of my validation work for the Subject model.

```
validates :url, :uniqueness => true
```

This above validation does not work and I get this but only when the url already exists:

```
SQL (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  Subject Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `subjects`.`id` FROM `subjects` WHERE (`subjects`.`url` = BINARY '78') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT `subjects`.`id` FROM `subjects` WHERE (`subjects`.`url` = BINARY '78') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I get forwarded to the existing record's subjects/show as if everything's great. Otherwise, when the url is unique, the exact same SQL query does not get rolled back and the record is created.

Any ideas how I should tackle this? Is this related to my custom subject routes? I'm pulling my hair out. Here's the rest of my routes:

```
  match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
  match '/about' => 'pages#about'
  match '/dashboard' => 'subjects#index', :as => 'user_root'

  get "pages/home"
  get "pages/about"

  resources :authentications

  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'} 

  resources :subjects do
    member do
      get 'stats'
      get 'comments'
      get 'qrcode'
      get 'download_qrcode'
    end
  end

  resources :traits
  resources :ratings
  resources :assets 

  match '/:url/stats' => 'subjects#stats'
  match '/:url/remove' => 'subjects#remove'
  match '/:url/comments' => 'subjects#comments'
  match '/:url/edit' => 'subjects#edit'
  match '/:url' => 'subjects#show'

  root :to => "pages#home"
```

Comment: it's not clear what the app is supposed to do. Is this like a tinyurl clone, except it's supposed to created a new Subject when hit with an unknown :url? Where is your Subject record created?

Comment: People will be creating a landing page for their subjects and they will be able to choose their one url e.g. domain.com/mysubject

Comment: Subjects are created normally in domain.com/subjects/new (create action) and redirected to domain.com/mysubjecturl after subject is saved. domain.com/X goes to subject/show. If subject does not exist with url X then it redirects to Rails.root.

Comment: Sounds like subjects_controller#create is redirecting as if it is successful, even when failing. Posting it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your routes file is OK.

Usually ActiveRecord rollback selects when you already have duplicated entries in your table, like multiple null or blank entries.
If you set the uniqueness validation after populate the table and you don't set an index into your migration file, probably that's the problem.

In this case, you can do:

- Insert index into your migration file:

  ```
  class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      ...
    end
    add_index :subjects, :url, :unique => true
  end
  ```
- Redo migrations and seed the table.

If this doesn't work, please send your migration file and active_record model.